# Memory efficient way to repartition a large dataset by key and applying a function separately for each group batch-by-batch

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a large spark scala Dataset with a `"groupName"` column. Data records are spread along different partitions. I want to group records together by `"groupName"`, collect batch-by-batch and apply a function on entire batch.
By "batch" I mean a predefined number of records (let's call it `maxBatchCount`) of the same group. By "batch-by-batch" I mean I want to use memory efficiently and not collect all partition to memory.

To be more specific, the batch function includes serialization, compression and encryption of the entire batch. This is later transformed into another dataset to be written to hdfs using `partitionBy("groupName")`. Therefore I can't avoid a full shuffling.

Is there a simple way for doing this? I made some attempt described below but **TL/DR** it seemed a bit over complicated and it eventually failed on Java memory issues.

---

**Details**

I tried to use a combination of `repartition("groupName")`, `mapPartitions` and `Iterator`'s `grouped(maxBatchCount)` method which seemed very fit to the task. However, the repartitioning only makes sure records of the same `groupName` will be in the same partition, but a single partition might have records from several different `groupName` (if #groups > #partitions) and they can be scattered around inside the partition. So now I still need to do some grouping inside each partition first. The problem is that from mapPartition I get an `Iterator` which doesn't seem to have such API and I don't want to collect all data to memory.

Then I tried to enhance the above solution with `Iterator`'s `partition` method. The idea is to first iterate the complete partition for building a `Set` of all the present groups and then use `Iterator.partition` to build a separate iterator for each of the present groups. And then use `grouped` as before.

It goes something like this - for illustration I used a simple case class of two Ints, and `groupName` is actually `mod3` column, created by applying `modulo 3` function for each `number` in the Range:

```
  case class Mod3(number: Int, mod3: Int)
  val maxBatchCount = 5
  val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Range(1,21))
     .toDF("number").withColumn("mod3", col("number") % 3)

  // here I choose #partitions < #groups for illustration
  val dff = df.repartition(1, col("mod3"))

  val dsArr = dff.as[Mod3].mapPartitions(partitionIt => {
    // we'll need 2 iterations
    val (it1, it2) = partitionIt.duplicate
    
    // first iterate to create a Set of all present groups
    val mod3set = it1.map(_.mod3).toSet
    
    // build partitioned iterators map (one for each group present)
    var it: Iterator[Mod3] = it2 // init var
    val itMap = mod3set.map(mod3val => {
      val (filteredIt, residueIt) = it.partition(_.mod3 == mod3val)
      val pair = (mod3val -> filteredIt)
      it = residueIt
      pair
    }).toMap

    mod3set.flatMap(mod3val => {
      itMap(mod3val).grouped(maxBatchCount).map(grp => {
        val batch = grp.toList
        batch.map(_.number).toArray[Int] // imagine some other batch function
      })
    }).toIterator
  }).as[Array[Int]]

  val dsArrCollect = dsArr.collect
  dsArrCollect.map(_.toList).foreach(println)
```

This seemed to work nicely when testing with small data, but when running with actual data (on an actual spark cluster with 20 executors, 2 cores each) I received `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

- Note in my actual data groups sizes are highly skewed and one of the groups is about the size of all the rest of the groups combined (I guess the GC memory issue is related to that group). Because of this I also tried to combine a secondary neutral column in `repartition` but it didn't help.

Will appreciate any pointers here,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right approach with the repartition + map partitions.
The problem is that your map partition function ends up loading the entire partitions in memory.

First solution could be to increase the number of partitions and thus reduce the number of groups/ data in a partitions.

Another solution would be to use partitionIt.flatMap and process 1 record at time , accumulating only at most 1 group data

- Use sortWithinPartitions so that records from the same group are consecutive
- in the flatMap function, accumulate your data and keep track of group changes.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Actually I was trying to do something similar in mapPartitions but instead of sorting, I used a mutable.Map of ListBuffer, but still wasn't able to get it to work, maybe I'll post another question about this.
What I don't understand is, why is my previous solution caused memory issue if I used iterators?

Comment: you are actually materializing the entire content of the iterator (the partition data)  when doing things like  it1.map(_.mod3).toSet. The trick is to the processing while iterating to avoid that

Comment: Meanwhile I got the other solution to work (using mutable.Map) but now I'm really curious about trying this solution again, trying to reduce memory consumption. Can it be my only bug here is in the Set collection? If I'd use mutable.Set and add to it in iterations, allowing GC to collect memory from already added records, will it solve the issue? I will go back to it as soon as I'll get the chance and will update here. Thanks for the help @Stéphane !